# converting 'formatted' .txt file into excel

Tags: r

I need to convert the following .txt file into excel file using R. The .txt file are formatted in the following way. Manual copy-and-paste conversion is not possible as the .txt file consists of dozens of tables (and the tables are much bigger). Direct importing is also not possible as the space used to define each column is not standard (sometime two space-bars, sometimes three).

```
Table 1:
header                a     b    c    d    e    f    g 
Dates
1.  Sept.23, 1983    1.2   3.2  3.4  5.7  6.2  3.4  4.5
2.  July 26, 1984          4.6  4.8  6.7  4.6  3.4  2.3
3.  April 20, 1985              4.6  4.5  3.6  7.1  9.8
4.  Oct. 22, 1985                    5.6  4.5  6.7  3.3
5.  Jan. 24, 1985                         6.9  3.4  2.3

Table 2:
header
. 
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be made simpler or harder depending on the assumptions you can make (number of columns, number of spaces after the date, ...)

The central part is to read the numeric fields and fill up empty columns with whitespace. Here is a function that can do that using the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

fill_left <- function(s, n_fields, col_names){
  str_split(s, " +") %>%
      map(~ .x[nchar(.x) > 0]) %>%
      map(~ c(rep("", n_fields - length(.x)), .x)) %>%
      as.data.frame(row.names = col_names) %>%
      t() %>%
      as_tibble()
}
```

You use `stringr::str_split()` to separate the numbers using whitespace (" +" is a regular expression, that means one or more whitespace). It returns a list, so the next steps are done with `purrr::map` that applies a function to every element of the list.

`.x[nchar(.x) > 0]`: remove empty strings
`rep("", n_fields - length(.x))`: generate a vector with empty strings of the right length, use `c()` to bind it with existing numbers. You can replace "" with 0.
Then I have several format conversions to end up with a tibble, it could probably be simplified.

So let's use the function on a single table:

```
table_content %>%
  str_split_fixed("    ", 2) %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "universal") %>%
  transmute(index = str_split_fixed(...1, "\\. ", 2)[,1],
         date = str_split_fixed(...1, "\\. ", 2)[,2],
         fields = ...2) %>%
  bind_cols(fill_left(.$fields, 7, letters[1:7])) %>%
  select(-fields)
```

We start with a table, split it on 4 consecutive spaces, then we can extract the index (row number) and date, keeping the numeric fields on hand. We can now apply our function to the numeric fields, we get a new tibble that we can join back with the rest. We finally remove the column we don't need anymore.

Now, a final question is left: what is the first step. If I understand your question, you have a single file with all tables, you can read everything in at once with:

```
file_content <- readLines("my/file.tab")
```

Then you will need some programming to cut the tables out. You can use `stringr::str_starts()` to find the lines with headers, and slice your file content:

```
table_content <- file_content[first_line:last_line]
```

Depending on your file, you might also need to gather the column names for each table.